# Getting errors while generating WSDL via mvn command

Tags: eclipse, maven

The location to my project is `C:\Users\ess\workspace\myproject1`. I tried to generate the wsdl file via the mvn command but this error appeared

`The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there no pom in this directory c:\users\ess`

and Maven home is `c:\program files\apache-maven-3.1.0`

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change to the directory where your `pom.xml` sits:

```
cd C:\Users\ess\workspace\myproject1
```

Make sure your `pom.xml` is located inside `myproject1`

Now run the maven command.

If still the error comes, please share your complete maven output.

Comment: some things to check here - What version of Java you are using, what is the plugin version of `jaxws-maven-plugin` you are using? Can you please add some details in your question (POM, complete maven error stack trace). Also try running maven with -X option.

Answer (score 1):

the location where you are trying to execute the command is not the root directory of the maven project. Check whether at this location `C:\Users\ess` you have pom.xml, i don't think you have.

Now go to this location `C:\Users\ess\workspace\myproject1` and try to run the same command again.

Comment: dude you need a windows tutorial first . anyways go to command prompt
   `cd C:\Users\ess\workspace\myproject1`
and then enter ur maven command .